# How to set font-size to an evaluated value in emacs?

Tags: fonts, emacs

I am new to emacs lisp and trying to set a keyword value to a evaluated expression like below:

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:height (+ 70 70)))))
)
```

Note that initially the height is a static value `140` and it works well. However when I changed it to an expression it failed with msg:

```
error: Default face height not absolute and positive, +, 70, 70
```

The reason why I am trying this is I am sharing same `.emacs` file on multiple computers with different screen sizes. So my ultimate goal is to calculate font size based on screen size.

What is the correct way to set a keyword value to an expression?

Comment: If you manually make changes to the custom section, then those changes may be somewhat lost if saving custom again using the built-in methods.  For example, you can evaluate 70 + 70 to 140, but the next time you save custom through normal built-in methods, the value will be 140, not spelled out as 70 + 70.  That being said, you can try changing the single quote to a backtick and place a comma before the section to be evaluated; i.e., try:  `(default ((t (:height ,(+ 70 70))))) .  See:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html  You can do this outside of custom .

Comment: @lawlist thanks. works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what lawlist says, it's completely reasonable.  If you want to do this outside of customize:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height (+ 70 70))
```

No need for quasiquotes because the expression isn't quoted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and I constantly plug and unplug my monitors and use the Mac Retina display.

I found `default-text-scale` works nicely. If your setup uses `use-package` here is what I've configured.

```
(use-package default-text-scale
    :ensure t
    :config
    (setq default-text-scale-amount 8)
    :bind
    ;; Plus makes it better
    ("M-+" . default-text-scale-increase)
    ;; Underscore makes it smaller (- is already bound)
    ("M-_" . default-text-scale-decrease))
```

It doesn't solve your specific problem but it works across all windows with adjusting font sizes. Comes in handy if you ever need to present.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you tried to do, but use code that gets evaluated, not code that is protected from evaluation by `quote`.  For example, use a *backquote* expression: change your quote to a backquote and put a comma before the sexp you want evaluated.

```
(custom-set-faces
 `(default ((t (:height ,(+ 70 70))))))
```

That's equivalent to this:

```el
(custom-set-faces
 (list 'default (list (list t (list :height (+ 70 70))))))
```